# Force redirect https to http(main domain pointing to sub folder)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(staging.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/staging/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /staging/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(staging.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ staging/index.php [L]
```

How do I force all https request to http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} /on/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://hostname/$1 [L,R]
```

The rule must be a redirect to switch from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: Where do I add the rule, on top or below the existing rules?

Comment: I would make it the very first rule to bounce HTTPS over to HTTP immediately. The HTTP request will then skip over it and hit your existing ruleset.